# mbedOS Uvisor+LCD=program stops working, on STM32f429 discovery

Tags: lcd, stm32f4discovery, mbed

I'm a beginner using mbed OS and Embedded programing in general, i want to become familiar with mbed OS and uvisor and my aim is to use the LCD screen to print or not the secret in the secured box.
so when i juste use mbed-library with uvisor disabled, everything works perfectly. But when i try to enable uvisor library, my program stops working. I've tried implementing a simple example using mbed OS+uvisor and it works well. I hope you can help me, thank you in advance.

Here is my code :
main.cpp:

```
#include "mbed-drivers/mbed.h"
#include "minar/minar.h"
#include "core-util/FunctionPointer.h"
#include "uvisor-lib/uvisor-lib.h"
#include "lcd.h"
#include "main.h"
#include "btn.h"


/* messages on LCD */
char uvisorhello[] = " *** uvisor-Hello ***";


using mbed::util::FunctionPointer0;

/* Create ACLs for main box. */
MAIN_ACL(g_main_acl);

/* Enable uVisor. */
UVISOR_SET_MODE_ACL(UVISOR_ENABLED, g_main_acl);

DigitalOut led(MAIN_LED);
DigitalOut red_led(RED_LED);


void toggle_led()
{
  led = !led;
}



void init_periph()
{

  /* Init LCD */
  init_LCD();

  /* Configure the pushbutton. */
  btn_init();
}


void main_prog()
{
  toggle_led();
}



void app_start(int, char**){

    init_periph();

    lcd_print(uvisorhello);

    minar::Scheduler::postCallback(toggle_led).period(minar::milliseconds(1500));

}
```

main.h :

```
void  lcd_print(char *str);
void lcd_clear();
void toggle_led();

#define LED_ON  true
#define LED_OFF false

#define MAIN_LED LED1
#define RED_LED LED2

#define MAIN_BTN USER_BUTTON
#define MAIN_BTN_PD PullDown



#define MAIN_ACL(acl_list_name)                           \
    static const UvisorBoxAclItem acl_list_name[] = {     \
        {TIM2,   sizeof(*TIM2),   UVISOR_TACLDEF_PERIPH}, \
        {TIM5,   sizeof(*TIM5),   UVISOR_TACLDEF_PERIPH}, \
        {GPIOA,  sizeof(*GPIOA),  UVISOR_TACLDEF_PERIPH}, \
        {GPIOG,  sizeof(*GPIOG),  UVISOR_TACLDEF_PERIPH}, \
        {GPIOC, sizeof(*GPIOC), UVISOR_TACLDEF_PERIPH}, \
        {GPIOD, sizeof(*GPIOD), UVISOR_TACLDEF_PERIPH}, \
        {GPIOF, sizeof(*GPIOF), UVISOR_TACLDEF_PERIPH}, \
        {SPI5, sizeof(*SPI5), UVISOR_TACLDEF_PERIPH}, \
        /* FIXME: Secure RCC/EXTI/SYSCFG/FLASH */         \
        {RCC,    sizeof(*RCC),    UVISOR_TACLDEF_PERIPH}, \
        {EXTI,   sizeof(*EXTI),   UVISOR_TACLDEF_PERIPH}, \
        {SYSCFG, sizeof(*SYSCFG), UVISOR_TACLDEF_PERIPH}, \
        {FLASH,  sizeof(*FLASH),  UVISOR_TACLDEF_PERIPH}, \
        {PWR,    sizeof(*PWR),    UVISOR_TACLDEF_PERIPH}, \
        {(void *) 0x42470000, 0x1000, UVISOR_TACLDEF_PERIPH}, \
    }
```

lcd.cpp :

```
  #include "lcd.h"




/* Font size structure */
TM_FONT_SIZE_t FontSize;


void init_LCD()
{

  /* Init LCD */
  TM_LCD_Init();

  /* Fill LCD with color */
  //TM_LCD_Fill(0x4321);


}

void lcd_print(char *str)
{
  /* Verify if the bottom of the screen is reached*/
  if(TM_LCD_GetCurrentY()>TM_LCD_GetHeight())  lcd_clear();
  /* Put string to LCD */
  TM_LCD_Puts(str);
}

void lcd_clear()
{
  TM_LCD_SetXY(0,0);
  TM_LCD_Fill(0xFFFF);
}
```

lcd.h

```
#include "lib/stm32fxxx_hal.h"
#include "lib/tm_stm32_disco.h"
#include "lib/tm_stm32_delay.h"
#include "lib/tm_stm32_lcd.h"
#include "main.h"


void init_LCD();
void lcd_print(char *str);
void lcd_clear();
```

Comment: This was ages ago, but likely you have not requested the appropriate ACLs. The MPU will trigger an exception if you access memory that your box did not explicitly request via an ACL.

Comment: Indeed, problem was solved, but thanks for your reply